# How to inject serializer as argument on a Symfony event listener

Tags: symfony, serialization

My code :

**<kbd>Services.yml</kbd>**

```
 acme_api.event.jwt_created_listener:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\JWTCreatedListener
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @serializer ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: lexik_jwt_authentication.on_jwt_created, method: onJWTCreated }
```

**<kbd>Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\JWTCreatedListener</kbd>**

```
    namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

    class JWTCreatedListener {
       public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, Symfony\Component\Serializer\

Serializer $serializer) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }


    public function onJWTCreated(\Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\JWTCreatedEvent $event) {

        $data = $event->getData();
        $songs = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Favsong')->findByUser($user);
        $data['songs'] = $this->serializer->serialize($songs, 'json');

        $event->setData($data);
    }
}
```

I'm just trying (with no success) to encode a doctrine object to a json using the serializer encoder. I feel that I'm probably missing some point when declaring the services. Also I'd like to know where is documented the available options to use on the arguments yml section, as I'm always copying from examples, and trying to guess as now with @serializer. I think I'm missing some official SF2 document.

Comment: What do get in return? Error? Empty `array`?

Comment: Just a 500 from apicall.html when sending the ajax call:
http://uvx/api/login_check 500 (Internal Server Error)
If I remove the falsy serializer injection and I don't try to serialize anything then I get a 200 OK request.

Comment: What does the log say? `HTTP 500` is merely just a final outcome...

Comment: Argument 2 passed to Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\JWTCreatedListener::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer, none given

Answer (score 1):

You're most probably missing the leading backslash (`\`) in front of argument type hint. So instead of:

```
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer $serializer
```

do:

```
\Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer $serializer
```

Does this fix the issue?

Comment: You're right but still the error seems to be related with the argument used on services.yml

"Notice: Undefined variable: serializer"

Comment: That seems odd. Can you update your question with full PHP class of that event listener?

Comment: the lines are now added, just the class title and namespace. I think the key is on knowing where to find the available arguments to be used on services.yml.

Comment: I think your `service.yml` is just fine.  On which line does it raise that `Undefined variable` error? You also don't have `serializer` class member... PHP might be able to figure that out but it's a bad practice

Comment: Ok, thanks. The error is on the argument line (L36) on service.yml

Comment: I get those errors all the time :) Still everything turns out to be ok even if IDE reports errors in `XML`/`YML`...

Comment: Well, good to know :)  But unfortunately the serializer is still not available from the listener. Do you know were to be sure that I can use @serializer as an argument on services.yml? I'd like to read some official doc about this...